# Not recognizing "@" from SQL query in Java Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

I keep getting **unexpected char '@'** error in Java(hibernate) when trying to execute this query. Here is part of the code, I find important for my issue:

```
Session s1 = null;
    Transaction tx1 = null;
    List<PpaDrCdr> resultSet = null;

    String query = "select "+ "id "+ "from name_of_the_table@name_of_the_database " 
try{
        SessionFactory factory1 = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        s1 = factory1.openSession();

        tx1 = s1.beginTransaction();

        resultSet = s1.createQuery(query).list();

        tx1.commit();

    }catch(HibernateException ex){
        if(tx1 != null){
            tx1.rollback();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(s1!=null && s1.isConnected()){
            s1.close();
        }
    }
```

Error appears at this line: **resultSet = s1.createQuery(query).list();** and it says **unexpected char @**

On the other hand, when I execute this query at sql editor, it works perfectly and returns expected rows from the table.

I guess the problem is that Java is not recognizing @ character.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this ??

I tried to change ojdbc drivers, but it keeps giving the same error with all three ojdbc5, ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 drivers.

I really don't have idea what else I can do.

Comment: Are you using a native query?

Comment: @LAZARUSS what you tried to execute the query? can u put the sample code? How you are executing query?

Comment: You do not need to add database name in your query, hibernate will take that from your datasource properties ie. persistence.xml

Comment: That's not a correct HQL query. The code is bad in other ways too, but you'd need to use a native query to use SQL in your query. I recommend tutorials and lots of them.

Comment: @shi I dont have persistance.xml or properties file, only Hibernate.cfg.xml file and there I declared database I need to connect to. Tricky part is, that I cannot acces the table from the query directly. I have to connect to one database and from there, by link, I go to the other database, where my table from the query is located

Comment: @Kayman I am beginner in using Hibernate, but dont have lot of time to read tutorials because of project deadlines, so I would be thankful if you could tell me more precisely on which parts to focus

Comment: Hibernate is a large enough component as its own, so there's no "quick tips" that would help you master it quicker. You can spend your time reading, or you can spend your time battling with problems.

Comment: @Lazaruss try with createSQLQuery

Comment: Believe it or not, but createSQLQuery solved the issue. Thank you very much karelss !!